# Ajax Form does not return in html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

My ajax code is:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {

            if(data.nameValidate == true && data.emailValidate == true && data.messageValidate == true) {
                $("form").fadeOut("fast", function() {
                    $("#contact").append('<p class="sent">' + data.success + '</p>').fadeIn("slow");
                });
            };

        }
    });
```

What must I add to mail.php's echo part to give a success message in HTML.
PHP is sending mail but isn't give success message to ajax.

I tried to put something here but nothing is working. I wrote some html codes like `echo "<p>.....</p";`  but it showed them in a blank page.

```
<?php
    $isim=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $konu=$_POST['subject'];
    $mesaj=$_POST['comments'];
    $telefon=$_POST['phone'];

    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "mail.website.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "iletisim@website.com";
    $mail->Password = "*******";
    $mail->From = "iletisim@website.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->FromName = " Iletisim Formu";
    $mail->AddAddress("example@website","example@website.com");
    $mail->Subject = "'".$isim."' adli kisiden mesajiniz var.";
    $mail->IsHTML(true); 
    $mail->Body = 'Isim: '.$isim.
        "<br/><br/>"."e-Mail: ".$email.
        "<br/><br/>"."Telefon: ".$telefon.
        "<br/><br/>"."Konu: ".$konu.
        "<br/><br/>"."Mesaj: ".$mesaj;

    if($mail->Send())
    {
          // I try to put something here but nothing is working. I Write some html codes like echo "<p>.....</p";  but it showed them in a blank page.
    } else {
         echo '<font color="#F62217"><b>Bir Hata OluÅŸtu. LÃ¼tfen Telefonla UlasmayÄ± Deneyiniz.</b></font>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: try to alert("somethink"); to check if the sucess function get executed

Comment: You say your PHP doesn't returns the message so could you include your PHP too?

Comment: i think- mail.php must return something data.nameValidate as 1(success) but ı dont know how to do it

Comment: `dataType: json` means you expect json back. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Jasen, Thanks for your answer but i dont know anything about json. the ajax form is not mine and i cannot convert ajax form to phpmailer. html codes of the page is not suitable for the <form action="contact.php">

Comment: Remove the `dataType` option or set it to `html`.

Comment: can you give me a code which i can write between if($mail->send()) and else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the data in PHP
The following should work wiuth your javascript/jquery

```
if($mail->Send())
{
    $data['nameValidate'] = true;
    $data['emailValidate'] = true;
    $data['messageValidate'] = true;
    $data['success'] = 'Oh it\'s working';
} else {
     $data['fail'] = '<font color="#F62217"><b>Doh</b></font>';
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Also change your javascript to:

```
if(data.nameValidate == true && data.emailValidate == true && data.messageValidate == true) {
    $("form").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $("#contact").append('<p class="sent">' + data.success + '</p>').fadeIn("slow");
    });
}else{
    if(typeof(data.fail)=="string"){
        $("#contact").append('<p class="sent">' + data.fail + '</p>').fadeIn("slow");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array or an object with the data you want to return to the ajax success function and encode it using the PHP function [json_encode](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).